# React: Importing all components from a folder

Tags: react-native

I'm starting my adventure with React and I wanted to ask if there exist a way to import all components from a single folder at once instead each one separatelly, like in Python: `from folder_name import *`

I looked similiar questions, but none seemed to have a solution for it (mostly had created one additional file in with the files were imported separatelly, but it's not what I search for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately something like this can't be done in JS/TS overall not just in react, no javascript transpiler has ever added this functionality, i guess they never found it useful enough to be added.
The closest solution to what you're looking for is exactly what you found, where you create one more file where you import all the components and then export them in one object, something like the following:

```
import Component1 from './components/Component1';
import Component2 from './components/Component2';
import Component3 from './components/Component3';

export default {Component1, Component2, Component3};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is a components folder in the React project.
You can create index.js in that folder and then you can try with this code.

```
export { default as Component1 } from './Component1';
export { default as Component2 } from './Component2';
```

And then you can import like this.

```
import { Component1, Component2 } from './components';
```